# error on g++ 4.8.2 at list method-argument default initialization

Tags: c++, list, c++11, initialization

I am trying the new features of c++11 and I found an issue. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
        int f (list<string> a, list<string> b={})
        {
            cout << a.size() << endl;
            cout << b.size() << endl; // This line!!!
            return 0;
        }
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    list<string> l{"hello","world"};
    a.f(l);
    return 0;
}
```

the execution stuck at "This line!!!" line. I continue debugging and it looks like the problem is here.

```
       /**  Returns the number of elements in the %list.  */
       size_type
       size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
```

I compile my program in this way:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb3 -fPIC -o test TestlistInit.cpp
```

I am using this version of g++:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I get same problem on 4.7.3, interestingly just replacing `list<string> b = list<string>()` works. But yeah, seems like a gcc bug.

Comment: Definitely a bug. You get a [segmentation fault](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1764458721a56fc) when you return it from a function as a default argument. And look what happens [when the list contains elements.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa7a009908546074)

Comment: incredible that such elementary bugs are still in 4.8.2 ...

Comment: This seems to be working on g++ 4.9.1 (on Debian)

Answer (score 2):

To find the cause, enable debug symbols, and when you get to first line, we first check contents of b, which looks like this (the value will be different) In this case I used Code::Blocks "Watch" option.

```
b.M_Impl._M_node._M_next = 0x7fffffffe370
b.M_Impl._M_node._M_prev = 0x7fffffffe370
```

Then use debugger option to "Step into" once we hit our b.size line.

Eventually this will take us to stl_iterator_base_funcs.h

At start we can see first & last are same:

```
__first._M_node = 0x7fffffffe370
__last._M_node = 0x7fffffffe370

 while (__first != __last)
{
  ++__first;
  ++__n;
}
```

Stepping into `++__first` we can see it does this in stl_list.h :

```
_Self&
operator++()
{
_M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
return *this;
}
```

`_M_node` and and `_M_node->_M_next` are the same, so `__first` never increments, and `.size()` is caught in endless loop.